Abaqus umat calls other subroutine but it doesn't update the array
I use the simple isotropic elastic material in uniaxial tension as an example. First the isotropic elastic behavior is directly coded inside the UMAT subroutine and it works fine below (OK.for).
Now I coded the isotropic elastic behavior in a separate subroutine (see "mymodel" in NOTOK.for below) and then let UMAT call mymodel subroutine. However it doesn't work and after printing out the parameter (C) when calling/after-calling mymodel subroutine, it shows that the parameter (C) is not updated in UMAT after calling mymodel subroutine. This is strange because Fortran passes parameters by adresses so the parameter should be automatically updated in UMAT.
Could anyone help to check the problem? All files (includinng Abaqus .inp) are given below. Thanks very much!
OK.for
      subroutine umat(stress,statev,ddsdde,sse,spd,scd,
     1 rpl,ddsddt,drplde,drpldt,
     2 stran,dstran,time,dtime,temp,dtemp,predef,dpred,cmname,                       
     3 ndi,nshr,ntens,nstatv,props,nprops,coords,drot,pnewdt,
     4 celent,dfgrd0,dfgrd1,noel,npt,layer,kspt,jstep,kinc)
     
      include 'aba_param.inc'
      
      character*80 cmname
      dimension C(6,6)
      dimension stress(ntens),statev(nstatv),
     1 ddsdde(ntens,ntens),ddsddt(ntens),drplde(ntens),
     2 stran(ntens),dstran(ntens),time(2),predef(1),dpred(1),
     3 props(nprops),coords(3),drot(3,3),dfgrd0(3,3),dfgrd1(3,3),
     4 jstep(4) 
     
 
      E=3.5e9
      XNU=0.346
      
      XK=E/3.0/(1.0-2.0*XNU)
      G=E/2.0/(1+XNU)
      
      C=0.0
      C(1,1) = XK+4.0/3.0*G
      C(2,2) = C(1,1)
      C(3,3) = C(1,1)
      C(4,4) = G
      C(5,5) = G
      C(6,6) = G
      C(1,2) = XK-2.0/3.0*G
      C(1,3) = C(1,2)
      C(2,3) = C(1,2)
      C(2,1) = C(1,2)
      C(3,1) = C(1,2)
      C(3,2) = C(1,2)     
      

      print '("C=")'
      print *,C   
      ddsdde=C

       DO i=1, NTENS
       DO j=1, NTENS
           STRESS(j)=STRESS(j)+DDSDDE(j, i)*DSTRAN(i)
       END DO
       END DO     

      print '("ddsdde=")'
      print *,ddsdde

      end 

NOTOK.for
      subroutine umat(stress,statev,ddsdde,sse,spd,scd,
     1 rpl,ddsddt,drplde,drpldt,
     2 stran,dstran,time,dtime,temp,dtemp,predef,dpred,cmname,                       
     3 ndi,nshr,ntens,nstatv,props,nprops,coords,drot,pnewdt,
     4 celent,dfgrd0,dfgrd1,noel,npt,layer,kspt,jstep,kinc)
     
      include 'aba_param.inc'
      
      character*80 cmname
      dimension C(6,6)
      dimension stress(ntens),statev(nstatv),
     1 ddsdde(ntens,ntens),ddsddt(ntens),drplde(ntens),
     2 stran(ntens),dstran(ntens),time(2),predef(1),dpred(1),
     3 props(nprops),coords(3),drot(3,3),dfgrd0(3,3),dfgrd1(3,3),
     4 jstep(4)
     
     
  
      call mymodel(C)
      print '("C=")'   ! here output extremely large and random numbers, different from C above
      print *,C   
      ddsdde=C

       DO i=1, NTENS
       DO j=1, NTENS
           STRESS(j)=STRESS(j)+DDSDDE(j, i)*DSTRAN(i)
       END DO
       END DO     

      print '("ddsdde=")'
      print *,ddsdde

      end 
      
 
      
      subroutine mymodel(C)
      
      dimension C(6,6) 
      
      E=3.5e9
      XNU=0.346
      
      XK=E/3.0/(1.0-2.0*XNU)
      G=E/2.0/(1.0+XNU)
      
      C=0.0
      C(1,1) = XK+4.0/3.0*G
      C(2,2) = C(1,1)
      C(3,3) = C(1,1)
      C(4,4) = G
      C(5,5) = G
      C(6,6) = G
      C(1,2) = XK-2.0/3.0*G
      C(1,3) = C(1,2)
      C(2,3) = C(1,2)
      C(2,1) = C(1,2)
      C(3,1) = C(1,2)
      C(3,2) = C(1,2)
      
      print '("C=")'     ! output C correctly here
      print *,C   

      end 

test.inp
*Heading
** Job name: matrix Model name: Model-1
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 6.14-1
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
** PARTS
**
*Part, name=Part-1
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=Part-1-1, part=Part-1
*Node
      1,           1.,           1.,           1.
      2,           1.,           0.,           1.
      3,           1.,           1.,           0.
      4,           1.,           0.,           0.
      5,           0.,           1.,           1.
      6,           0.,           0.,           1.
      7,           0.,           1.,           0.
      8,           0.,           0.,           0.
*Element, type=C3D8
1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 4, 3
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet2, internal, generate
 1,  8,  1
*Elset, elset=_PickedSet2, internal
 1,
** Section: Section-1
*Solid Section, elset=_PickedSet2, material=MAT0
,
*End Instance
**  
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet4, internal, instance=Part-1-1, generate
 5,  8,  1
*Elset, elset=_PickedSet4, internal, instance=Part-1-1
 1,
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet5, internal, instance=Part-1-1, generate
 1,  4,  1
*Elset, elset=_PickedSet5, internal, instance=Part-1-1
 1,
*End Assembly
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=MAT0
*Depvar
     12,
*User Material, constants=1
0.,
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=NO, inc=2
*Static, direct
0.5, 1., 
** 
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: BC-1 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
_PickedSet4, 1, 1
_PickedSet4, 2, 2
_PickedSet4, 3, 3
_PickedSet4, 4, 4
_PickedSet4, 5, 5
_PickedSet4, 6, 6
** Name: BC-2 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
_PickedSet5, 1, 1, 0.01
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field, variable=PRESELECT
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history, variable=PRESELECT
*End Step


Edit 1: aba_param.inc is added below
aba_param.inc
      implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
      parameter (nprecd=2)


Without the include file we can't say anything for certain.

But at the same time, the include file is a part of proprietary software and could be pretty big (something like mpif.h). Unfortunately, it might be the case, that only Abaqus experts will be able to answer. Isn't there technical support provided with the Abaqus license?

@VladimirFГероямслава Well as a hack you could include it in the called subroutine and see if that fixes things. I'm worried about something like an Implicit in it. Which is horrible, but given the above you deserve what you get.

Hoverstar: Coud you add the line Write( *, * ) Kind( C ) just before both times you print out the values of C and edit the question to report what it says. A quick google suggests Abaqus hides an Implicit statement in the include file, which is evil and could be causing the problems you are having.

@VladimirFГероямслава The file aba_param.inc is added, please see Edit 1 section.  Note this file is software-specific and it is located in the installation folder of abaqus.

@hoverstar it is only included in one of the routines. My guess is you have to include it in both

@IanBush, after adding the line Write( *, * ) Kind( C ), inside the mymodel subroutine, it gives 4; while inside UMAT subroutine, it gives 8.

OK, the problem is that C is of different kinds in the two subroutines. You do need to include the file in both places

@IanBush it gets worse!  Not only does Abaqus hide an implicit statement in aba_param.inc, but the Abaqus build system swaps out what kind it assigns.  This has been the bane of my existence
